# Postgresql: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information

Tags: arrays, postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_old_transactions (IN p_fromdate date, IN p_todate date, IN p_transtype varchar,IN OUT p_cancelled boolean,
OUT p_transaction_date date,
OUT p_type varchar,
OUT p_description varchar,
OUT p_amount numeric)


RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$

declare lRunQuery text; 
declare lTotalRec record;
declare lBranchList text[]; 
declare lTranstype text[]; 


BEGIN

select into lTranstype
    dt.type

from
    v_data_types dt;


    lTranstype := regexp_split_to_array(p_transtype, ',');

lrunquery := 'select
it.transaction_date trandate,
dt.type,
it.description,
ita.amount,
it.cancelled


from 
import_transaction it
inner join import_transaction_account ita on it.import_transaction_id=ita.import_transaction_id



where
it.transaction_date >= ' || quote_literal(p_fromdate) || '
and it.transaction_date <= ' || quote_literal(p_todate) || '
and dt.type = any(' || quote_literall(p_transtype) || ') and';

if (p_cancelled = TRUE) then
lrunquery := lrunquery || '
it.cancelled = ' || quote_literal(p_cancelled) || '';
else
lrunquery := lrunquery || '
it.cancelled = ' || quote_literal(p_cancelled) || '';
end if;



FOR lTotalrec in
    execute lRunQuery


LOOP
p_transaction_date := ltotalrec.trandate;
p_type :=ltotalrec.type;
p_description :=ltotalrec.description;
p_amount :=ltotalrec.amount;
p_cancelled := ltotalrec.cancelled;
return next;
END LOOP;

return ;
end;


$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
COST 100
ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION  f_old_transactions(date,date,varchar,boolean) OWNER TO "CompuLoanPostgres";

select * from f_old_transactions ('01-Jan-2010','31-Dec-2018','Receipt Cash','FALSE')
```

I'm getting an error that my array value must start with "{". My array I'm trying to create is from a view **v_data_type** the view consist of only one column with a varchar type.

Can anyone please direct me where the issue in my code is?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've given us enough information to know for certain what's going wrong. Notably, I have no idea what the tables should look like, either in schema or content. Without that, I can't build a test case in my own DB to debug.

That said, I noticed a couple things, specifically around the `lTranstype` variable:

1. You're assigning `lTranstype` twice. First you `SELECT INTO` it, and then you immediately assign it to a value unpacked from the `p_transtype` argument. It's not clear to me what you want in that variable.
2. When constructing your query later, you include `and dt.type = any(' || quote_literall(p_transtype) || ')`. The problem is that `p_transtype` is a varchar argument, and you're trying to access it like an array. I suspect you want that to read `and dt.type = any(' || quote_literall(lTranstype) || ')`, but I could be mistaken.

I'm guessing that your type error is coming from that second problem, but it seems like you need to reassess what the different variables in this function are intended for. Good luck.